# Power supply safety standards

Tags: power-supply, power, low-power, security

I want to build radio/alarm clock that power itself from the wall. I live in Canada. What safety standards should I follow? And is it free to acquire the datasheet of these safety standards or does it cost money to acquire such document?

Comment: Security? Are you worried about your radio being stolen?

Comment: Seriously? No i don't want to get electrocuted by it....

Comment: Ah, that would be _safety standards_ then.

Comment: You mean *safety* standard? Often the standards aren't free, but that's the least of your problems. Following all applicable regulations would be difficult, costly and time consuming, especially since you would have to get your device certified by a third party. If you are making a one-off device as a hobby project and are worried about safety, simply get a suitable off-the-shelf low voltage power adapter and use it to power the circuitry.

Comment: Getting a product approved through safety standards (something like UL) could cost like $10k

Comment: CSA in Canada, UL in the US, and the price is out of this world for any hobby project (not to mention having samples tested to destruction does not typically work well for hobby projects.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal is it even legal to sell a non certified product?

Comment: In the old days, many mains powered clocks used the mains frequency for timekeeping. Not sure if this is what the OP intends to do. But the utilities used to take great care to keep the long term frequency error minimal. Old mains powered clocks kept perfect time for years and years without ever being adjusted. Not sure if the utilities still do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it's not *that* big a deal.  The simple way is to do an end-run around all these issues:  Use a low-voltage wall-wart power supply which *is* UL/CSA/CE listed.  The rest of your project falls under the low-voltage rules, which are  more relaxed.

If you absolutely need 120V inside the box (why?), make it an all-metal box and ground it, use listed devices for anything that portrudes, and be safe inside. How else can anything get prototyped?

By the way, for access to the standards, there is a bit of a rebel movement going on.  It rejects the notion of creating a de-facto secret law by referencing a private entity's standard and subcontracting the private entity to selectively paywall, signupwall, creditcardwall, agewall, classwall, enemy-of-the-state-wall, etc. The standards organizations are answering this by providing some degree of freer access. So you may be able to get access one way or another.

Comment: More free to certify the safety of a product? COOL! Though I wonder where you got that information from...

Comment: More free access to the standards documents. Obviously you have to work with a listing agency to certify a product, and they need some sort of motivation to work with you, usually money.

Comment: Well if you got an invention, and they approve of its potential success, they gotta say yes.